# Proof of Lie Derivative property

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, lie-derivative

I was reading through the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) for a Lie Derivative, and it states the following property in the bottom of the section "The Lie Derivative of a differential form"

$L_{fX}w = fL_X w + df \wedge i_X w$

I haven't seen this stated before, does anybody know of a textbook that proves this? It seems like it follows from Cartans identity but I was struggling to prove it to myself.

Comment: An approach that I’ve always found useful is the following: If an identity looks like one you already know but you don’t see how to use the known one to prove the new one, try adapting a *proof* of the known one to prove the new one. Here, I also suggest using local coordinates. You can figure out the abstract proof later.

Comment: Another approach (probably easier in this case) is to use [Cartan's magic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formula).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach which doesn't use the local coordinates or Cartan's formula, at least directly. First assume $\omega$ is a 1-form, then the formula you've written is a formula of 1-forms, so it is true iff it is true upon testing on arbitrary vectors fields $Y$. Testing on $Y$ is allows us convert from a Lie derivative of a 1-form to a Lie derivative of a vector field which is much friendlier to deal with.

Since Lie derivative is a derivation, it satisfies the following product rule
$$X(\omega(Y))=(\mathcal{L}_X \omega)(Y)+\omega(\mathcal{L}_X Y).$$
Therefore, we compute
\begin{align*}
(\mathcal{L}_{fX}\omega)(Y)&=(fX)(\omega(Y))-\omega(\mathcal{L}_{fX}Y)\\
&=f(X(\omega(Y)))-\omega(f\mathcal{L}_XY-(Yf)X) \\
&=f(X(\omega(Y))-\omega(\mathcal{L}_XY))+(Yf)\omega(X)\\
&=f(\mathcal{L}_X \omega)(Y)+df(Y)\wedge\iota_X \omega,
\end{align*}
where the second equality is from the computation
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_{fX}Y&=(fX)Y-Y(fX)\\
&=f(XY)-(Yf)X-f(YX)\\
&=f[X,Y]-(Yf)X\\
&=f(\mathcal{L}_XY)-(Yf)X.
\end{align*}

Now the general case, as usual with these proofs, is nothing more than bookkeeping. If $\omega$ is an $n$-form, then we must test on $n$ vector fields $Y_1,...,Y_n$. We compute
\begin{align*}
(\mathcal{L}_{fX}\omega)(Y_1,...,Y_n)&=(fX)(\omega(Y_1,...,Y_n))-\sum_{i=1}^n\omega(Y_1,...\mathcal{L}_{fX}Y_i,...,Y_n)\\
&=f(X(\omega(Y_1,...,Y_n)))-\sum_{i=1}^n\omega(Y_1,...,f\mathcal{L}_XY_i-(Y_if)X,...,Y_n)\\
&=f(\mathcal{L}_X\omega)(Y_1,...,Y_n)+\sum_{i=1}^n\omega(Y_1,...,(Y_if)X,...,Y_n)\\
&=f(\mathcal{L}_X\omega)(Y_1,...,Y_n)+\sum_{i=1}^n df(Y_i)\wedge\omega(Y_1,...,X,...,Y_n)\\
&=f(\mathcal{L}_X\omega)(Y_1,...,Y_n)+(df\wedge \iota_X\omega)(Y_1,...,Y_n).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the response Zack, can you explain the final line of the proof? Where does the wedge product come from?

Comment: The wedge product is just to match your formula. If you notice, the $\iota_X \omega$ is just a function, so the wedge product here is just, at a point, scalar multiplication.

Comment: @ZackFox The original question is about any differential form, not only $1$-forms, so maybe a word on the general case would be a good idea

Comment: Oh huh, I somehow completely missed that. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll edit this in a bit.